# Infinte page reload when submitting form with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the value of an input field and then submit the form before the whole document is loaded but when i run this code my page keeps reloading by itself.

```
<form action="" id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="likedItems" name="likedItems" value=''>
</form>

<script>
    let hiddenInput = document.querySelector("#likedItems");
    hiddenInput.value = 1;
    let test = document.getElementById("myForm");
    test.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: That's because you're submitting the form with Javascript on every page load with `.submit()`, and form submissions cause page loads.

Comment: `<form action="someOtherPage.php" ` ?

Comment: If you want to submit a particular field then you have to use `ajax get`  instead of form posting...